# How does the ThreadPool work?

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, concurrency, task-parallel-library

Exactly how do the threadpool in TPL work? Several blogs says that it works like:

- The thread first checks its local queue
- The thread then checks the global queue
- And at last the thread checks the surrounding local queues

However, the book *Concurrent Programming on Windows* by Joe Duffy, says that it works like:

- The thread first checks its local queue
- The thread then checks the surrounding local queues
- And at last the thread checks the global queue

Who's right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blogs seem to be correct in this case;

> it first looks at the head of its local queue, then in the global
>   queue, and then in the local queues of other threads.

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402.aspx), see "Work Stealing"

Comment: It would just make more sense if it checked the surrounding local queues first, to reduce the locks on the global queue...

Comment: The global queue has been improved in .NET 4 to use a lock-free algorithm, avoiding any potential performance issues created by going to the global queue before surrounding local queues.

Comment: The [CLR 4.0 ThreadPool Improvements](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericeil/archive/2009/04/23/clr-4-0-threadpool-improvements-part-1.aspx) blog post by Eric Eilebrecht is a good start.